# Finding reflection of a matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation, transformational-geometry, reflection

To 2 decimal places, what is the value of the lower-right entry in the reflection matrix $Q_a $if a = 1.05?

Not even sure where to begin, is there a formula?

This is what I could find in my textbook
[image]

Comment: "in the reflection matrix $Q_a$" - what is the definition of $Q_a$ ?

Comment: Thats it the question I was given.

Comment: @Belgi this has to do with transformations

Comment: There is no universal definition of $Q_a$.  You're going to have consult your textbook, class notes, or your instructor to determine the meaning of this symbol before proceeding.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I have edited my question please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well the lower right entry of the matrix $q_a$ is $-\cos(2a)$.  So plug in $a = 1.05$ and use a calculator to get an approximate value for $-\cos(2.10) \approx 0.50485$.  Be sure to use 'radian' mode on your calculator.  (Always assume angle measures for trigonometric functions are in radians unless explicitly told otherwise.)

Comment: thats exactly what I was thinking as well.. but with one exception that I did not use radian mode I will do that now